# UTF8 from web content .xml file to NSString

Tags: iphone, xml, utf-8

I can't find a way to convert some UTF8 encoding into NSString.

I get some data from a URL, it's a .xml file and here is their content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
<name>Jim Fern&#225;ndez</name>
<phone>555-1234</phone>
</person>
```

How can I convert the & #225; into a á ?

some code that doesn't work:

```
 NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

### edit:

I'm using the [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm using the [NSString+XMLEntities](http://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+XMLEntities.m) from Michael Waterfall to decode .xml