# Cocos2D and UTF-8 (german characters)

Tags: encoding, utf-8, cocos2d-iphone, cclabelttf

I have a .xml file containing some text. The text also has some German charcters (ä, ü, ö) in it.
The XML file is encoded as UTF-8, wich makes it appear fine in every text editor and xcode.

But when showing the text on a Cocos2D CCLabelTTF (iPhone/iPad), the special characters get messed up. They are replaced by one or two ugly characters I have never seen before ;-)

Should I use a different encoding? Or is there a way to make Cocos2D get that right?

BTW: If I enter the same text directly into xcode (without using the xml file), the text shows up correctly on the label...

Comment: show how you read the xml file please. This is not about cclabelttf since direct entry in xcode produces the expected outcome.

Comment: I'm using TBXML (http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html).

Comment: look here see if it applies : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070374/utf8-from-web-content-xml-file-to-nsstring